# how to change xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing value

Tags: wcf

I have to change xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing. How we can acheive that before sending request in WCF.

I tried to do it using Assertion and policy but it removed my all security headers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configurating the `textMessageEncoding` element on the binding? Please refer to [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731787(v=vs.110).aspx) on documentation to set the `messageVersion`. (documentation is incomplete; versions Soap11 and Soap12 are also available to my knowledge).